# Illegal counter variable in FOR loop - Pascal

Tags: loops, variables, pascal

Mayby problem is inside the enviroment [I use replit]; but someone can help me understand step by step why I can't use counter in that way? In another/second compiler [dev-pascal] result is correct, but I get back  information about last part of syntax when I try to use destructor: matrix1.free is not a statement.

What I must modify?

P.S.

Sorry for my English, but is not my native languge.

```
{$MODE OBJFPC}
{$M+}
uses
  SysUtils, crt;

const
  n = 10;

type
  matrix = class
    public 
      t: array [1..n, 1..n] of integer;
      i, x, y, sum: integer;

      procedure read_data();
      procedure process_data();
      procedure show_data();
  end;

  procedure matrix.read_data();
  begin
    randomize();

    for x := 1 to n do
      for y := 1 to n do
      begin
        if (x = y) then
          t[x, y] := random(10)
        else
          t[x, y] := 0;
      end;
  end;

  procedure matrix.process_data();
  begin
    sum := 0;
    i := 0;

    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
      if (x = y) then
        sum := sum + t[i, i];
    end;
  end;

  procedure matrix.show_data();
  begin
    for x:=1 to n do
    begin
      for y := 1 to n do
        write(t[x, y], #9);

      writeln();
    end;

    writeln('suma liczb z przekątnej: ', sum);
  end;

var
  matrix1: matrix;

begin
  matrix1 := matrix.create;
  matrix1.read_data();
  matrix1.process_data();
  matrix1.show_data();
  matrix1.free;
end.
```

Why I can't use global initialization?

I read inter alia

https://comp.lang.pascal.borland.narkive.com/uzQCbC7K/why-illegal-counter-variable

https://gitlab.com/freepascal.org/fpc/source/-/issues/36065

> *Note that this depending on mode is a global variable initialization which will be unsafe if your code runs multiple times.*
>
> *If you are doing this for "always initialization" reasons, initialize in code, since in declaration initialization is ambiguous in FPC.*

> *It is clear that for new code, where initialization is allowed at declaration, this exception is not supported (bad style is not supported).
>
> FPC in this sense is compatible*

Comment: `for` loop control variables must be local to the procedure where they occur.

Comment: dev-pascal is a 2005 era IDE, and can have multiple different compilers.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, the counter variable for your `for` loop must be scoped to the procedure where it is being used.

This:

> ```
>  procedure matrix.show_data();
>  begin
>    for x:=1 to n do
>    begin
>      for y := 1 to n do
>        write(t[x, y], #9);
>
>      writeln();
>    end;
>
>    writeln('suma liczb z przekątnej: ', sum);
>  end;
> ```

Should be written:

```
  procedure matrix.show_data();
  var
    x, y: integer
  begin
    for x := 1 to n do
    begin
      for y := 1 to n do
        write(t[x, y], #9);

      writeln();
    end;

    writeln('suma liczb z przekątnej: ', sum);
  end;
```

In which case, you will find `x` and `y` no longer need to be declared as public member variables for your `matrix` class.